# Decile Sales Responsiveness is Statistically Invalid - Need Help Explaining Exactly Why

Tags: least-squares, independence

A common approach to sales force call planning analysis is Decile Responsiveness. Here's an outline:

1. Collect two year's of account level sales data (e.g. 2015 and 2016) and one year of sales force call data (e.g. 2016)
2. The accounts are put into deciles based on **2016 sales** (decile 10 being the accounts with the highest sales)
3. Each decile corresponds to 10% of the total sales (i.e. Decile 10 has the most accounts)
4. A OLS regression model is created where the **dependent variable is the 2016 sales**, and the independent variables are 2015 sales and ln(2016Calls + 1) for each decile, with no intercept. This is normally accomplished in a single model with separate independent ln(call + 1) variables for each decile.

**Is it valid to create deciles with the dependent variable?**

Take Decile 10 as an example; you're selecting the accounts with the highest sales and then saying the calls generated those sales, along with a carryover effect from the 2015 sales. Surely with this decile grouping (based on the dependent variable) any attribute of the Decile 10 accounts would show a significantly impact on sales. I suspect even if you substituted your competitor's calls for your calls they would still seem to have a positive coefficient on the 2016 sales.

**Assuming that this approach is invalid, what is the most succinct way of explaining / proving it's invalid?**

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "valid"?  So far, you have not told us how people are using this model, which precludes the possibility of assessing how well it might work for its intended purpose.

Comment: The model is normally used to allocate future selling effort. You can apply a profit margin to the curve and then the optimum effort is where the cost of a call is equal to the marginal return.

Comment: Thank you.  In order to determine whether this procedure is valid, then, we would need to know specifically how all this works: what it means to "apply a profit margin" to a curve and how the marginal returns are computed.  Then you need to describe how all this actually is used to allocate the selling effort.  Finally, "valid" could still be interpreted in various ways, ranging from "works better than guessing" to "is provably the best way to allocate selling effort."

Comment: By "valid" I mean "is a significant coefficient an indicator of a meaningful causal relationship". Or is this manipulation (i.e. creating deciles out of the dependent variable) a "trick" which always shows a statistically significant relationship?